# Fibonacci Recursion with Python

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

## I have the following exercise:

"Write a recursive function that prints the n-th number of the fibonacci sequence. The function parameters are 'n','current_number' [F(0)] and 'next_number' [F(1)]. [F(0)] and [F(1)] are the initial seeds of the sequence. Write the main program that ask user for the input parameters. Your code must output the result as follows.

```
fibon({n},{current_number},{next_number}) = {result}
fibon(5,4,5) = 37
fibon(5,0,1) = 5
fibon(10,0,1) = 55
```

## The following solution seems to work

```py
def fibon(n, current_number, next_number):
    #print(f'n is {n} from the outset')
    if n == 0:
        #print('n == 0 is true')
        return current_number
    elif n == 1:
        #print('n == 1 is true')
        return next_number
    else:
        n = n-1    
        #print(f'this is n-1 {fibon(n-1, current_number, next_number)}')
        #print(f'this is n {fibon(n, current_number, next_number)}')
        fib= fibon(n-1, current_number, next_number) + fibon(n, current_number, next_number)
        #print(fib)
        return(fib)
```

However, I don't understand how 'fibon' is returning the value of nth number in fibonacci series. It is a recursive function and I don't understand how every time it loops, it gets the fibonacci number for the nth position. If you look at the code, " fibon(n-1, current_number, next_number) + fibon(n, current_number, next_number)" can only return a number when n== 1 or n==0. If so, how it can reutrn other numbers in the position when they are not in the 1th or 0 position?

I am not sure if I made a lot of sense but I tried to express my confusin. Thanks in advance!

The code is working but I do not seem to understand why it is working. You can also propose a better solution if there is one. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello Daniel, it is a bit hard to edit the code here. So, I have shared here: https://www.pythonmorsels.com/p/2depa/

Comment: Thank you for looking into it!!

Comment: A minor warning, if your teacher hasn't mentioned it: 1) Fibonacci is a terrible thing to solve with recursion (without caching, it does exponential work, `O(2ⁿ)`, where an iterative solution is `O(n)`). 2) Python in particular is a bad language for recursion; the reference interpreter, and probably others, can't do tail call optimization, and set a relatively low bound for recursion depth. If the call stack exceeds that limit, you die with a `RecursionError`.

Comment: Between #1 and #2, you'll have a range of inputs that will take "heat-death-of-the-universe" time to complete, followed by all inputs larger than roughly `sys.getrecursionlimit() * 2` (the multiplier being due to how your recursion is currently structured; the limit is typically on the order of 1000-3000, depending on build settings and tweaks by third-party tools like IPython), which will die *immediately* due to excessive recursion in the initial linear path down to `fib(0)`.

Comment: Hello ShadowRanger, thank you for your detailed and well written response! Actually, I knew the problems with using recursion. However, we still need to use recursion so that we can practice and understand how it works. What I don't understand about this code is that what it returns everything the recursion takes place and why. Thank you in advance!